# Unable to import api yaml definition through aws console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, swagger-2.0

I have been trying to import my api definition file which is a yaml file but when I import it from console I am getting several errors

```
Invalid model name specified: application/json=null

Model name must be alphanumeric: inline_response_200_1

Invalid model name specified: null

Reference to model 'inline_response_200_1' not found. Ignoring.
```

How can I get rid of these ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I saw your post on GitHub as well, but these are validation errors in the import. Any models defined will have to have valid names which are alphanumeric [a-zA-Z0-9]+

It seems like you might have some bad YAML syntax because the model name should be non-null.

If a model isn't created successfully because of an error, any references in Methods will also be broken.

Comment: I have validated the YAML but still there are errors